# highlight.js : How do I tell it ignore default css

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

I'm trying to implement highlight.js.
I have and index.html.  andside the body is

```
<p>Example code</p>
<pre>
  <code class="html">
      <title>Title</title>

      <style>body {width: 500px;}</style>

      <script type="application/javascript">
        function $init() {return true;}
      </script>

      <body>
      <p checked class="title" id='title'>Title</p>
      <!-- comment to be highlighte -->
      </body>
  </code>
</pre>
```

But when I load the page, whatever is inside the `<pre>` is processed as true html and it ruins the page, also the main css im using on the page is applied to the tags inside the

In head of my index.html I have included
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/highlight.css">`

and before the body closing tag I included

```
<script src="../scripts/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
      hljs.highlightBlock(block);
     });
   });
</script>
```

I keep reading through the documentation, but can't seem ti find out what did I miss.

Answer (score 0):

So I just found out in case of trying to display html inside the pre tag all html characters need to be scaped. Keeping everything as it was I adjusted the script to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
        var string = $(this).html();
        $(this).text(string);
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
});
```

and that does the trick. (taking each of the code elements, grabbing the inner html and parsing it back as text)